# How to use multiple flatpages models in a django app?

Tags: django, django-middleware, django-flatpages

I have multiple models that can be converted to flatpages but have to have some extra information (For example I have an about us page but I also have a blog).
However I understand that there must be only one flatpages model since the middleware only returns the flatpages instance and does not resolve the child models.
What do I have to do?

EDIT:
It seems  I need to change the views.
Here's the current code:

```
from django.contrib.flatpages.models import FlatPage
from django.template import loader, RequestContext
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.xheaders import populate_xheaders
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_protect

DEFAULT_TEMPLATE = 'flatpages/default.html'

# This view is called from FlatpageFallbackMiddleware.process_response
# when a 404 is raised, which often means CsrfViewMiddleware.process_view
# has not been called even if CsrfViewMiddleware is installed. So we need
# to use @csrf_protect, in case the template needs {% csrf_token %}.
# However, we can't just wrap this view; if no matching flatpage exists,
# or a redirect is required for authentication, the 404 needs to be returned
# without any CSRF checks. Therefore, we only
# CSRF protect the internal implementation.
def flatpage(request, url):
    """
    Public interface to the flat page view.

    Models: `flatpages.flatpages`
    Templates: Uses the template defined by the ``template_name`` field,
        or `flatpages/default.html` if template_name is not defined.
    Context:
        flatpage
            `flatpages.flatpages` object
    """
    if not url.endswith('/') and settings.APPEND_SLASH:
        return HttpResponseRedirect("%s/" % request.path)
    if not url.startswith('/'):
        url = "/" + url

    # Here instead of getting the flat page it needs to find if it has a page with a child model.
    f = get_object_or_404(FlatPage, url__exact=url, sites__id__exact=settings.SITE_ID)
    return render_flatpage(request, f)

@csrf_protect
def render_flatpage(request, f):
    """
    Internal interface to the flat page view.
    """
    # If registration is required for accessing this page, and the user isn't
    # logged in, redirect to the login page.
    if f.registration_required and not request.user.is_authenticated():
        from django.contrib.auth.views import redirect_to_login
        return redirect_to_login(request.path)
    if f.template_name:
        t = loader.select_template((f.template_name, DEFAULT_TEMPLATE))
    else:
        t = loader.get_template(DEFAULT_TEMPLATE)

    # To avoid having to always use the "|safe" filter in flatpage templates,
    # mark the title and content as already safe (since they are raw HTML
    # content in the first place).
    f.title = mark_safe(f.title)
    f.content = mark_safe(f.content)

    # Here I need to be able to configure what I am passing in the context
    c = RequestContext(request, {
        'flatpage': f,
    })
    response = HttpResponse(t.render(c))
    populate_xheaders(request, response, FlatPage, f.id)
    return response
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going about this wrong.  No need to change the views at all.  The contrib Flatpages app is built for one specific purpose, "flat pages" i.e. pages like your About page, so use it for that.  For a blog, you're going to (either now or in the future) vastly different functionality, so use a separate app for that.  There are several "blog" apps out there already or write your own simple one.

From your question it seems you've written some models that inherit from Flatpages, which is ok I guess, but seems sort of silly to me for such a small model to begin with. If that's the case what you need to do is write your own views, in your own app, that use those models, not expect the Flatpage app to know anything about them.  Hope that helps!

Comment: It just strikes me odd that I have to violate DRY for this. I already have a model which supplies what I need, but has to be extended to fit to certain types of pages. Why do I have to create a whole new model with exactly the same info?

Comment: It's not clear why you're bringing Flatpages into this. What you've posted, especially the phrase "can be converted to flatpages but have to have some extra information" doesn't really tell me 1) what you have, 2) what your goal is, or 3) why you want to use Flatpages in pursuit of that goal.

Comment: 1) I have blog posts, about me/solutions pages and code snippets pages. All have content, title and everything else that a flat page has but some carry extra information (like programming language or tags). 2) My goal is to reduce work and repeative code. 3) Flatpages include the basics for what I need.